# Yahoo Webhosting 301 redirect without htaccess

Tags: redirect, yahoo

Is there any other possible ways to redirect non-www domain to with www domain (from http://example.com to http://www.example.com). I signed up for yahoo ecommerce solution and i am using a custom template with store tags. Yahoo does not allow htaccess to be uploaded to their servers and informed me that it is not possible to do a redirect from non-www domain to www domain, which is absurd.

Answer (score 0):

If you manage DNS-zone for domain, you can try CNAME www to non-www IP (I can't be sure is useful results)

Answer (score -1):

You have to create an "HTML redirect". This is a client-side redirection and tells the browser to request another page.

To create an HTML redirect page, you use the HTML meta tag, along with the 'http-equiv' and 'content' attributes.

To create an HTML redirect, place the following code between the document's head tags.

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="5; url=http://www.hostname.com/index.php">
```

In the above example, the page will redirect to the specified page in 5 seconds (as indicated in the 'content' attribute).

You can also use JavaScript to redirect to another web page

Comment: Thanks for the response but unfortunately this approach doesn't work since www version and non-www version files are the same files and it causes page to refresh every 5 seconds.

Comment: Terrible idea as SEO doesn't transfer and it's obnoxious to go to the site, then have to refresh, and some plugins block browser redirects/refreshes.

Answer (score -1):

Will javascript do?

```
if (!/^www\./.test(document.domain)) {
  top.location.replace('www.' + document.domain);
}
```